# jQuery - resize an elements height to match window without refreshing, on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script that works okay if page is refreshed but I want to be able to dynamically get the size of the resized window without refreshing the page and apply respective height to a section.

```
var w = $(window).width();
var h = $(window).height();

$('section').height(h);
```

What am I missing to make it work more dynamically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following, the function will be called every time the window is loaded or resized:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
    var w = $(window).width();
    var h = $(window).height();

    $('.section-content').height(h);
});
```

You confirmed in the comments that `section` should in fact be `.section-content`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/uPw6D/1)

Comment: hmm..weird. It works perfectly on your fiddle but it doesn't on my working files. I guess the window load function should be inside `document ready` function. Either way, no luck for me.

Comment: Yes, otherwise `section` won't exist when the function is called and you won't see a difference. Additionally, are you sure you have a `section` element and not another element with `.section` class given to it?

Comment: Oops my bad. I was missing a period on a class name. May I ask, why would you suggest using `load resize` instead of just `resize`? Thanks!

Comment: So it is `.section`? I will edit. If you don't add a `load` listener in there the section won't initially get resized. It will only resize when you resize the window.

Comment: I see. The actual class name used in my working file is `.section-content`. I just used `section` for the brevity of question.

Comment: Just one more thing. In this context, does `width()` do anything? I guess I should use `$('section').height(h).width(w);` to make better use?

Comment: You are right, `$(window).width()` is assigned to `w` but is never actually used. Your suggestion would definitely work.

Comment: @SeongLee `$(window).on('load'` for pages full of stuff might be too slow. Take care to apply your changes as soon as possible (read: `document.ready`)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var w = $(window).width();
    var h = $(window).height();
    $('.section-content').height(h);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting height width on window resize.

**[Window resize height/width change Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/LAF4G/)**

**Jquery:**

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
var h=($(window).height();
var w=$(window).width();
$('.section-content').height(h);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function setToWinSize(){
    var win = $(window);
    $('section').width(win.width()).height(win.height());
}

$(function(){        // on DOM ready

  setToWinSize();    

  $(window).resize(function(){
     setToWinSize();
  });

});
```