# jQuery disabling navcollapse <767px

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've used jQuery matchHeight on a page, and I've just noticed that it is stopping the Navbar Collapse from opening when it readjusts for screens 767px or smaller.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">

<div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand">Progression</a>
        <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="physio.html">Physio</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a>Massage</a></li>
        <li><a href="beauty.html">Beauty</a></li>
        <li><a href="firstaid.html">First Aid</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

</div>

</nav>
```

matchHeight

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('.boxtext').matchHeight();
 });    

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('.boximg').matchHeight();
 });
```

I've tried 2 different approaches to disable the jQuery for <767px screens, firstly CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 767px) {
  .boxtext {
    height: auto !important;
  } 
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 767px) {
  .boximg {
    height: auto !important;
  } 
}
```

And secondly; Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($(window).width() > 767){

                  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       $('.boxtext').matchHeight();
   });  

     jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       $('.boximg').matchHeight();
   });

   }
});
```

Neither of which have worked :(
Any help getting the Navbar working for smaller screen sizes would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20118754/jquery-resize-an-elements-height-to-match-window-without-refreshing-on-window

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with jquery-match, you're using a link (`a` tag) instead of the default button for your toggle, either switch it to a `button` or add `role="button"` to the link. `<a role="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">`

Comment: I'm not using default button because i don't like the stying. And the 3 pages that I'm not using matcghHeight on the nav links all work at screen sizes less than 767px. Hence that's i why think matchHeight is causing the problem